# Preventing of incorrect state with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have component

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const data = {
  "1": ["1a", "1b"],
  "2": ["2a"]
};

const slugs = {
  "1a": { text: "Lorem" },
  "1b": { text: "ipsum" },
  "2a": { text: "..." }
};

const ExamplePage: React.FC = () => {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIndex(0);
  }, [id]);

  console.log("state", {
    id,
    index
  });

  const slug = data[id][index];
  const text = slugs[slug].text;

  function onPrev(): void {
    if (index <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    setIndex((index) => index - 1);
  }

  function onNext(): void {
    if (index >= data[id].length - 1) {
      return;
    }

    setIndex((index) => index + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onPrev}>Prev</button>
      <span>{text}</span>
      <button onClick={onNext}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

And Route for this:

```js
<Route path="/:id" component={ExamplePage} />
```

Live version: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-ewl4d

There is a bug with this code when:

1. User is on `/1` url
2. User clicks button "Next"
3. User clicks link to `/2` url

In this case `id` will be `"2"`, `index` will be `1`, but there isn't `data["2"][1]`.

As you can see `useEffect` don't help in this case because `useEffect` don't stop current function call.

**My question is: How I can ensure that this state will be always correct?**

I know that I can write `const text = slugs[slug]?.text;` and this solve my bug, but still, in one moment, component have incorrect state. I wondering if is a way to prevent this incorrect state.

In React class component this problem can be solved by `getDerivedStateFromProps` - You can see this live on https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-solve-in-react-component-xo43g

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` will run async so you are trying to set the `slug` and `text` before the index has updated.

You can put the `slug` and `text` into state and then use another `useEffect` to update them when the `index` or `id` changes:

```
const { id } = useParams();
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const [slug, setSlug] = useState();
const [text, setText] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setIndex(0);
}, [id]);

useEffect(() => {
  const newSlug = data[id][index];
  if (!newSlug) return; // If id changes but index has not updated yet

  setSlug(newSlug);
  setText(slugs[newSlug].text);
}, [id, index]);
```

Comment: This works. But the problem with this code is that you can now produce inconsistent data. "Slug" should be always
result of "id" and "index" values. This breaks principle "single source of truth"